# Square Brackets in Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am having a silly doubt in vector .In this following code

```
 std::vector<char>ve(2);  //creates a vector ve of size 2    
 std::vector<char>vechar[2];   //but what does it do ?
```

in **ve vector** I can write

```
ve[0]='a';
ve[1]='b';
```

but I cannot write

```
vechar[0]='a';
vechar[1]='b';
```

also I cannot do

`std::cout << " vector -->>" << vechar[0];`

It shows error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `std::vector<char>vechar[2]` declares an array consisting of two vectors of `char` (it's the same syntax as used in, for example, `int arr[2]`).

Thus, `vechar[0]` is one vector of `char`, and `vechar[1]` is another vector of `char`.

Both vectors start off empty, but can be resized.

Comment: But then why I can't  write vechar[0]='a', we can do the same in array

Comment: @MsFreedom911: You can't assign a `char` to an entire vector.

Comment: One doubt .We have vechar[0] which is a vector of char and at some point its size becomes 5 after inserting elements then how can we access the 5th element of vechar[0] and how can we print the elements of vechar[0]?

Answer (score 5):

Adding more to the answer of NPE .To add character 'a' to vechar[0] or vechar[1] we have to do the following things

```
vechar[0].resize(10);
vechar[1].resize(10);
vechar[0][0]='a';         //means vechar 0 0th element
vechar[0][1] = 'b';        //means vechar 0 1th element

vechar[1][0]='c';
vechar[1][1]='d';

std::cout<<vechar[0][0]<<vechar[0][1];
std::cout<<vechar[1][0]<<vechar[1][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<char> v[10];`

The above declaration creates an array of 10 empty vectors, same as int v[10];

Answer (score 0):

Great Explanation by NPE,,,,,Adding to him and How can I Assign 'a' to vechar[0] and 'b' to vechar[1], according to me as follows...........

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector<char>vechar[2]; 

   vector<char> v1{'a'};
   vector<char> v2{'b'};

   vechar[0] = v1;
   vechar[1] = v2;

   //display the 'a' and 'b'

   cout << vechar[0][0] << endl;       //also may use vechar[0].at(0)
   cout << vechar[1][0] << endl;       //also may use vechar[1].at(0)

    
   return 0;
   }
```

output:
a
b