# whats the difference between vector<int> arr[n] and vector<int> arr(n)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, graph, declaration

```
#include <bits/std c++.h>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int n; cin>>n;
vector<vector<int>> array[n];//idk what this is`
vector<vector<int>> arr(n);//this means size of array is n
please tell me difference between them
}
```

I am new at coding but I am not really getting what this is so please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between vector<int> a , vector<int> a\[n\] and vector<int> a(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014089/what-is-the-difference-between-vectorint-a-vectorint-an-and-vectorint) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073735/square-brackets-in-vectors

Comment: OT: Whoever told you about [`<bits/std c++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
vector<vector<int>> array[n];
```

creates an array named `array` of size `n` with elements of type `vector<vector<int>>`. That is, each of the element inside this `array` is a 2D vector.

While the statement:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(n);
```

creates a 2D vector with `n` elements each of which is a 1D `std::vector<int>`.